# Using Java 8 lambda to convert Map of Lists to different Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have data that is like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> = // psuedocode
[
 {
  "ID": "a",
  "Value": "val1"
 },
 {
  "ID": "b",
  "Value": "val2"
 },
]
```

I want to turn this to

```
Map<String, String> = // more pseudocode
{
 "a": "val1",
 "b": "val2"
}
```

I have something like this so far:

```
    Map<String, String> output = myList.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap())
```

Can someone please guide me? The alternative is to use regular for loops, but I am trying to use lambdas.

Comment: Rather than pseudo-code, it would be helpful if you could come up with a [mcve]. That would stop everyone else having to do the duplicate work of creating a small test. The fact that your code so far doesn't refer to "ID" or "Value" is somewhat surprising... it sounds like you should be mapping each `Map<String, String>` into a single key-value pair, basically...

Answer (score 5):

You need to map each `Map` instance in the list to a key and a value, then collect into a single `Map` instance.

```
Map<String, String> output = myList.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("ID"), m -> m.get("Value")));
```

This will throw an exception if an "ID" is duplicated. There are overloaded methods that give you more control over this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

while above solution is great, I got the result as follows:

```
//declared a result map
Map<String, String> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

list.parallelStream().forEach( m -> result.put(m.get("id"), m.get("value")));
```

You could be safe in concurrent processing situations.